# Open a folder _DirName

Tags: windows-xp, command-line

How can I open the folder "_Audio" in Windows XP?

Comment: Uh.... We need more information please.

What is this folder, where is it located, what uses it, etc...

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can

- Double click it

  [image]

  [image]

---

- Drag and drop it to Command Prompt

  [image]

  [image]

  [image]

Comment: b) would not work on vista, though on any os you could cd into the directory.

Comment: @Phoshi Sure about not working on Vista ? IIRC I've done it before and it did work :-s or maybe I haven't tried.

Comment: There's some fancy reason to do with UAC, it's the same reason cmd windows didn't have themed scrollbars and stuff. Works fine on 7 and XP, though.

Comment: @Phoshi - I see

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can just `explorer "FolderPath"`.